# Problem with the number of the elements of a set and its proper subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible that "a set" & it’s "proper subset" have same number of elements? Example?

Comment: For a finite set, this is not possible by definition. For an infinite set, if you define number of elements by cardinality it is possible.

Comment: Even integers $\subset \mathbb Z$.  And $\mathbb Z \subset \mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$.  .... And $\{1,2,3,4,.........\}\subset \{0,1,2,3,4,......\} \subset \{-1,0,1,2,3,4,......\}$.  But notice, the set *must* be infinite.

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb N$ have the same cardinality

Comment: @Deepak "For a finite set, this is not possible by definition" I'm not sure I'd say this is by *definition* but it clearly is so.  A basic property of finite sets with would be that every finite set has a specific number of elements (but that is not the *definition*, it's something to be proven and not likely at the OPs level) and that every proper subset would have fewer elements (this will also have to be proven) and thus the specific number of elements of the subset would be a smaller unequal number.

Comment: @fleablood It is fairly trivial from the definition of a *proper* subset that there is at least one element contained in the set that is not in the proper subset, meaning that the cardinality of the (finite) proper subset is necessarily smaller than that of the (finite) parent set. That's what I meant by "by definition" - it almost immediately follows from the definition of a proper subset.

Comment: Yeah, but that assumes a lot of "obvious" conditions that simply are taken for granted at this level.  But none of them are the definition.  And why wouldn't it apply for infinite sets?  How would you explain that "infinity $-1$" is as still infinity and not less.  If you actually get to the definition of finite sets there is nothing in the definition that says a finite set can't have two *different* number of elements.  This is absurd and obviously meaningless, but it *is* a property that must be proven.

Comment: A set is [Dedekind-finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) if no proper subset is equinumerous with it.  You need some form of the Axiom of Choice to show that this is equivalent to being finite in the usual sense.

Comment: Nitpick::   " it’s "proper subset""  A set will not have *one* proper subset.  It will have many.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "the number of elements".  Infinite sets, technically, do not have a "number of elements", they have *cardinality*.

A finite set "obviously" has a fixed and determined number of elements but that is actually something that must be, rather tediously and abstractly, proven (the proof and the definition of "finite set" are probably more abstract and abstruse than I want to get into).

If the set is finite, and it has a set number of elements, then any *proper* subset would have elements missing so the subset's number of elements will be fewer and thus a different number.

So no, no proper subset of a finite set can have the same number of elements as the original set.

But that does not hold up if the set is infinite.

But if the set is infinite we may remove elements and still leave an "infinite number" of elements.

So for instance $\{1,2,3,4,......\} \subsetneq \{0,1,2,3,4......\}$ both have the same infinite cardinality.  As do $\{2,4,6,8,.....\}=$ the even natural numbers $\subsetneq \{1,2,3,4,,.....\} = \mathbb N \subsetneq \mathbb Z \subsetneq \mathbb Q$.